# Getting ComboBox variable to store in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, combobox, save

I have an html page that gets data from 'hs_hr_employee' table and lays the info in a table on a web page. Then I have another table 'rights' which gets info from 4 columns from the 'hs_hr_employee' table and stores them in columns. In addition to those 4, the 'rights' table has an extra column 'Permissions'.

Now, I have a combobox with 4 options. When I click the 'Save' button I want to store the value select in the combobox and save it in the 'rights' table in relation to the user.

(Each user has a combobox next to it).

Updated code:

```
       <?php

 $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','root');
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['cb_permissions'] ) && is_array( $_POST['cb_permissions'] ))
    {
        foreach( $_POST['cb_permissions']  as $emp_number => $permission)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE `your_permission_table` SET permission='".mysql_real_escape_string($permission)."' WHERE emp_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_number)."'";
            echo __LINE__.": sql: {$sql}\n";
            mysql_query( $sql );
        }
    }
}
?>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size:36px;"><strong><span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 128);">File Database - Administration Panel</span></span></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid #666;
font-style:Calibri;
}
th
{
background-color:#666;
color:white;
font-style:Calibri;
}
</style>
</head>

    <form method="post" action="admin.php">

    <?php 


        if (!$connection)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db('users', $connection);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_lastname, emp_firstname  FROM hs_hr_employee");

        echo "<center>";

        echo "<table >
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_number'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['employee_id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_lastname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_firstname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td> <select name='cb_permissions['".$row['emp_number']."'><option value='all'>All</option> <option value='remote'>Remote Gaming</option> <option value='landbased'>Landbased Gaming</option> <option value='general'>General Gaming</option> </select> </td>"; 
          echo "</tr>" ;

          }

        echo "</table>";

        echo "</center>";

        echo mysql_query('INSERT into rights(Emp_num, ID, Name, Surname) SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM hs_hr_employee');

        $_POST['cb_permissions'];

        mysql_close($connection);

    ?>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<p style="text-align: right;">
    <input name="Save_Btn" type="button" value="Save" />


    </p>

</form>
```

Any help on how I can do it?

Screenshot to get a basic idea of what I'm doing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should move connection code at the very top of your documents:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','root'); 
if (!$connection)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('users', $connection);
```

Next, you have to wrap your table inside  tag:

```
<form method="post" action="target_url.php>
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

After that, you would store `employee_id` or `emp_number` (depending on what table key you will use for setting permission) somewhere on your form:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['employee_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_firstname']; ?></td>
    <td><select name="cb_permissions['<?php echo $row['emp_number']; ?>']">
        <option value='all'>All</option>
        <option value='remote'>Remote Gaming</option>
        <option value='landbased'>Landbased Gaming</option>
        <option value='general'>General Gaming</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Then, on your `target_url.php`, you will have to do:

> If `target_url.php` is the same as your form, then code below should be placed at the very top of your document.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['cb_permissions'] ) && is_array( $_POST['cb_permissions'] ))
    {
        foreach( $_POST['cb_permissions']  as $emp_number => $permission)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE `your_permission_table` SET permission='".mysql_real_escape_string($permission)."' WHERE emp_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_number)."'";
            echo __LINE__.": sql: {$sql}\n";
            mysql_query( $sql );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

That's it.

Comment: I'm getting this error on line 68 which is:  `echo "<td> <select name='cb_permissions['<?php echo $row['emp_number']; ?>']'><option value='all'>All</option> <option value='remote'>Remote Gaming</option> <option value='landbased'>Landbased Gaming</option> <option value='general'>General Gaming</option>   </select>  </td>";`

Comment: Error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin.php on line 68`

Comment: it should be:
"<td> <select name='cb_permissions['".$row['emp_number']."'><option value='all'>All</option> <option value='remote'>Remote Gaming</option> <option value='landbased'>Landbased Gaming</option> <option value='general'>General Gaming</option> </select> </td>";

Comment: Thanks, I get no errors now, but nothing will display on the screen i.e. the table is not showing. Any idea as to why it's happening? I updated the code in the main question.

Comment: use missed quote on your form:
<form method="post" action="admin.php>

it should be:
<form method="post" action="admin.php">

Comment: also, what is the purpose of this query:

echo mysql_query('INSERT into rights(Emp_num, ID, Name, Surname) SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM hs_hr_employee');

you should aware that query is execute every page load.

Comment: Thanks I didnt see the ". As for that query, I was coming to it. That should insert data from hs_hr_employee table into rights table as well as the selected value from the combobox. So the employee_id, employee_num, Firstname, Lastname and ComboBox values should be saved to the 'rights' table. The hs_hr_employee table is only used to gather data from it, and not to save to it. Everything is written in the rights table when the 'Save' button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest:

1. Use require_once( "db_connect.php" ) <- in this file make connection
2. Use smarty & html_options to show this drop down.

1 time your will learn this, next - using. Code will start be organized ... 
Maybe to complex for starter. But this is right Way.